# Result of call to 'onReceive(_:perform:)' is unused

Tags: timer, swiftui

The call to input is unused, I see some people use an _ but I get the same error. thank you

```
Text("Distance: \(self.travelDistance)").modifier(MainMenuModifier(trimColor: .green))
                    .onReceive(self.timer) { input in
                        self.latitude2 = location.coordinate.latitude
                        self.longitude2 = location.coordinate.longitude
                        self.travelDistance = self.calculateDistance(lat1: self.latitude1, lon1: self.longitude1, lat2: self.latitude2, lon2: self.longitude2)
                    print("travel distance: \(self.travelDistance)")
                }
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I think it is because this Text with .onReceive is located not in ViewBuilder context. Would  you show part of code where this Text is used?